# Quantum Optics Question Involving Coherent States

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator

Given the quantum-optics coherent states

$|\alpha \rangle = \exp \Big(-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}\Big) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n \rangle$

Show that

$\langle (\Delta X)^2 \rangle_{\alpha} = \langle (\Delta P)^2 \rangle_{\alpha} = \frac 1 4$

Where

$|n \rangle$ are the photon number states

$X=\frac{a+a^*}{2}$

$P=\frac{a-a^*}{2i}$

$a|\alpha \rangle = \alpha |\alpha \rangle$

My attempt:

$|\alpha \rangle = \exp \Big(-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}\Big) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n \rangle$

I've tried to square $\Delta X$ and $\Delta P$ compare  and  but they are not equal

I have to say I am pretty lost here and a hint would be appreciated.

I have studied coherent states and I know how to proof some properties related to it.

For instance, I see how to proof that the state is normalized:

$\langle \alpha|\alpha \rangle = \exp(-|\alpha|^2) \Big(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \langle m| \frac{\alpha^{*m}}{\sqrt{m!}}\Big) \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle \Big) $

Based on $\langle m | n \rangle = \delta_{mn}$ we indeed get $\langle \alpha | \alpha \rangle = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: What is $\langle\alpha |a| \alpha \rangle$? (you can find it from the fact that the coherent state is an eigenstate of $a$)

Then, what is $\langle\alpha |a^\dagger| \alpha \rangle$?
What are the values of $\langle\alpha| a^\dagger a| \alpha \rangle$, $\langle\alpha|a a^\dagger| \alpha \rangle$, $\langle\alpha| {a^\dagger} ^2| \alpha \rangle$ and $\langle\alpha| a^2| \alpha \rangle$?

Now, you can find $\langle\alpha |X| \alpha \rangle$, $\langle\alpha |P| \alpha \rangle$, $\langle\alpha |X^2| \alpha \rangle$, $\langle\alpha |P^2| \alpha \rangle$. (you have already written expressions of $X$ and $P$ in terms of $a$ and $a^\dagger$).

What are the expectation values of $\Delta X$ and $\Delta P$ in terms of these quantities?

Comment: I did not post the full answer as this is a homework type question.